# Oracle Forms Multirow block validation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-------------------+---------+
|Name               |Jr       |
+-------------------+---------+
|Name1              |N        |
|Name2              |N        |
|Name3              |N        |
|Name1Jr            |Y        |
|Name2Jr            |Y        |
|Name3Jr            |Y        |
+-------------------+---------+
```

And here is what my multirow block looks like:

[image]

What I want is that when I insert for example Name2, it will automatically add under it the same name with Jr. on its end and the property of the Jr checkbox will be uneditable and checked if the Name has Jr. on its end like this:

[image]

I tried in WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM of Name:

```
if :blk.name like '%Jr' then
    :blk.Jr := 'Y';
    set_item_property('blk.jr', enabled, PROPERTY_FALSE);
else  
    set_item_property('blk.jr', enabled, PROPERTY_TRUE);
end if;
```

But Jr becomes enabled if I enter another record that has no Jr in the end. I want it to be per row enable/disable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY` instead.

Comment: sir how about on how to insert record if the record I entered for example Name3, on the next line it will also insert Name3Jr

Comment: You'd `duplicate_record` and `:name := :name || 'Jr'`